# Determine the value(s) of $k$ for which this system has infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

Given this system, find the values of $k$ for which this system has infinitely many solutions:

$$x+2y+z=2$$
$$2x-2y+3z = 1$$
$$x+2y-(k^2-3)z = k$$

After applying Gaussian elimination we arrive at the following augmented matrix:

$$[A \ \ b ] =\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 1 & 2  \\
0 & -6 & 1 & -3  \\
0 & 0 & -(k^2-3)-1 & k-2  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now this system will have infinitely many solutions **iff** $$\left(-(k^2-3)-1 = 0\right) \land \left(k-2=0\right)$$.

But $\not \exists k \ni \left(-(k^2-3)-1 = 0\right) \land \left(k-2=0\right)$. Does that not imply that there doesn't exist a $k \in \mathbb{R}$, that would produce infinitely many solutions to this system? Have I made a mistake?, Are there other methods apart from Gaussian Elimination and trying to see if it produces a row full of zeros, to find out if a system will have no solution, a unique solution or infinitely many solutions?

Comment: It seems correct.

Comment: The $-(k^2-3)z$ in the Anton-Rorres text is probably a typo for $+(k^2-3)z$. Try it with the plus sign, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to is to check if there is any k such that rows of coefficients are not independent.It is very quick to find that when $k=\sqrt2$, row 1 and row 3 are not independent and thus can have infinite solution. I don't see $k=2$ has this features.